# What's the meaning of ^ and $ symbols in regular expression?

Tags: regex

What's the meaning of the symbols ^ and $ in regular expression.

For example :

> ^[SQBM][0-9]{5,6}$

Thanks

Comment: `^` starts with, `$` ends with.

Comment: See e.g. [Start of String and End of String Anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) or read the perlretut [Part 1: The basics: Simple word matching](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Simple-word-matching)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`^` is beginning of input and `$` is the end of it.

e.g.

- `^[0-9]` - everything that starts from a digit
- `[0-9]$` - everything that ends with a digit

And a little bit more detailed description from [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression):

- `^`  Matches the starting position within the string. In line-based tools, it matches the starting position of any line.
- `$`  Matches the ending position of the string or the position just before a string-ending newline. In line-based tools, it matches the ending position of any line.

Answer (score 1):

^ - beginning of text

$ - end end of text